# Modal bootstrap auto hide when i use tinymce

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, tinymce

I use tinymce in modal bootstrap. I use filemanager responsive upload Image. After I select image. My modal auto hide. When i not use tinymce, after upload image, my modal open. Help me fix error. Thank you everyone.

[Use tinymce](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WC-HVg9FOmU2dhFG6zcFgzdhZD_PiYT7)
[Not Use tinymce](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IXjapPLm6sU0NRLciajZOclq-_QoOEa8)

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can view two video i post Use tinymce Not Use tinymce

Comment: Sorry, you can temview me. Thank you